# Reliability of Path_INFO server variable in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, path

Am I always going to be able to use PATH_INFO to derive the root of my application as in the following function?

```
function CommonFunctions_getRoot()


    pathinfo=Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")

    Set myRegExp = New RegExp
    myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    myRegExp.Global = True
    myRegExp.Pattern = "^(/\w*/).*" 
    CommonFunctions_getRoot = myRegExp.Replace (pathinfo, "$1")


end function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PATH_INFO is reliable. The only problem I can think of is that you may have issues if you use URL rewriting.

Comment: Thanks! I don't do that; this is a plain-vanilla ASP app.