# Create (file) string with classic asp VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

In .net (C#) I use this to create a multiple file(name) string.

```
if (pic == null)
   pic += "filename";
          else
   pic += "~" + "filename";
```

I'm unfamiliar with ASP.Classic VBScript.
Can someone help me with syntax in ASP.Classic VBScript?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not really sure I understand the question. Could you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
if pic = "" then
    pic = pic & "filename"
else
    pic = pic & "~" & "filename"
end if
```

Erik

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this.

```
If IsNull(pik) Then
   pik = pik & "filename"
Else
   pik = pik & "~" & "filename"
End If
```

Comment: In C# an unassigned string variable is null.  However in VBScript a variable must be explicitly assigned `Null`.  Its unlikely that this is the case for the `pik` variable here.  In VBScript any unassigned variable has the value `Empty` which is considered equal to "" and 0.  Hence Rico is closer.

Comment: That Cool.  I should have also checked for IsEmpty(pik) as well.  I agree Rico's answer is more precise.  http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14197

Comment: @AnthonyWJones null value from database will also be VBNull.

Answer (score 1):

Rico answer is correct as far as syntax is involved, however classic ASP does not recognize the `~` character as the web application root - this is new "feature" of ASP.NET that has no direct equivalent in classic ASP.

One way to get the root is using such function:

```
Function GetApplicationRoot()
    Dim pathinfo, myRegExp
    pathinfo = Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")
    Set myRegExp = New RegExp
    myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    myRegExp.Global = True
    myRegExp.Pattern = "^(/\w*/).*" 
    GetApplicationRoot = myRegExp.Replace(pathinfo, "$1")
End Function
```

The above is based on the code found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508206/reliability-of-path-info-server-variable-in-classic-asp).

Having this, the complete answer will be:

```
If Len(pic)=0 Then
    pic = "filename"
Else  
    pic = pic & GetApplicationRoot() & "filename"
End If
```

Note that in VBScript, only empty database value will return `Null` all other strings will just be empty, meaning zero length.

In case `pic` **is** coming from database, change the code to:

```
blnNullOrEmpty = False
If IsNull(pic) Then
    blnNullOrEmpty = True
Else  
    If Len(pic)=0 Then
        blnNullOrEmpty = True
    End If
End If

If blnNullOrEmpty Then
    pic = "filename"
Else  
    pic = pic & GetApplicationRoot() & "filename"
End If
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the application root in .NET, but how is it different from server.mappath("/"), which will give you the absolute path to the root of the site?

Comment: When you have such link URL in .NET - **~/myfile.aspx** the "~" will be translated to the root folder e.g. in the HTML source you will see **/myroot/myfile.aspx** - there is not such thing in classic ASP.